# Web audio api unexpected syntax token, Sound won't play

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I get this  " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of nullaudioStuff.js:39 (anonymous function)"

In this line :

```
document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener('click', start);
```

I dont understand, the syntax seems to be ok for me, any ideas ?

Im running the app through a server with ruby in port 8000 i started with this code :

```
ruby -r webrick -e "s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd); trap('INT') { s.shutdown }; s.start"
```

This is the full code:

```js
function stop(){ 
    source.stop(context.currentTime); // stop the source immediately 
}

// Load the Sound with XMLHttpRequest 
function start() { 
// Note: this will load asynchronously 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open("GET", tune.wav, true); request.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // Read as binary data  

// Asynchronous callback 
request.onload = function() { 
var data = request.response;  
audioRouting(data);
};  

request.send(); 
}


// Create Buffered Sound Source 
function audioRouting(data) { 
    source = context.createBufferSource(); // Create sound source 
    context.decodeAudioData(data, function(buffer){ // Create source buffer from raw binary
    source.buffer = buffer; // Add buffered data to object 
    source.connect(context.destination); // Connect sound source to output 
    playSound(source); // Pass the object to the play function
    }); 
}


// Tell the Source when to play 
function playSound() { 
source.start(context.currentTime); // play the source immediately 
  }



document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener('click', start); 
document.querySelector('.stop-button').addEventListener('click', stop);
```

Comment: are you sure this javascript code is valid? I tried to parse it i got unmatched '{'

Comment: you can make use of http://jslint.com/ to parse this javascript code to get some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add event listener after page has been loaded.
Hence `document.querySelector('.play')` is returning `null` and hence the error
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of nullaudioStuff.js:39 (anonymous function)`

It is not finding elememt 'play' class.

```
$(document).ready(funtion(){
  document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener('click', start); 
  document.querySelector('.stop-button').addEventListener('click', stop);
});
```